# "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve ..." error in @import of scss

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass

I'm on VueJS 2 and recently upgraded to Webpack 5. Everything has been fine except I'm having some issues with some imports on my scss files.

For my setup, I have a site and an API that distributes some assets. The SCSS has some imports that pulls from the api. For example:

```html
<style lang="scss" scoped>
@font-face {
    font-family: MyAPIFont;
    src: url("/api/public_data/fonts/MyAPIFont.ttf") format("truetype");
}
</style>
```

The error I get is `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/api/public_data/fonts/MyAPIFont.ttf' in '...path to the vueJS file'`. It's trying to find the font in my project directory but I don't want it to - it's not bundled with the site.

Is there a way to ignore any imports from `/api/*` in webpack?

Comment: css-loader handles that see docs https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#url

Comment: @LawrenceCherone But it's SCSS (SASS). Looking for an example of webpack rules to ignore files in a specific path.

Comment: sure, but the options are set there. *The css-loader interprets @import and url() like import/require() and will resolve them.* is specifcally what css-loader does rtm link, its not todo with if its less/sass/css or not, that's the job of https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader etc